# What could give inconsistent figures on the number of files in a folder?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, file-management

In Windows XP, when I clicked "Properties" on a folder, it said

```
Size: 788 MB (826,867,591 bytes)
Size on disk: 806 MB (845,590,528 bytes)
Contains: 8,772 Files, 0 Folders
```

When I entered the folder, the bottom left hand corner said

```
9,512 objects
```

and when I selected all the items and did "Properties", it said

```
2,970 Files, 0 Folders

Size: 452 MB (474,082,998 bytes)
Size on disk: 457 MB (479,973,376 bytes)
```

I don't think any of the files are hidden - the only thing I can think of is that the folder hierarchy has gotton pretty deep at that stage.

I think the 9512 objects is the correct figure, based on running the following in git bash:

```
$ find . | wc
   9513    9513  785977
```

Answer (score 1):

When you right click on a folder and go to properties, it adds up all the files in the current folder, *as well as* all the files in the subfolders.

When you enter a folder and select all, it lists only the files in that folder as being selected, even if your selection includes a subfolder with files.  However, doing a "properties" on that selection will include the subfolders files.

Tested this on Win7, however XP might be a little different.

Im actually a little surprised at the inconsistencies.

Comment: This is exactly what is going on. I am not surprised, considering how long it takes to calculate size.